# Godot - D - Export Keyword

Tags: d, godot

I am trying to export a NodePath.

Whats the export keyword in Godot-d?

I've tried @export and @Export but still no luck.

Comment: Did you try `export`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `@Property` (not to be confused with similarly `@property` class function attribute).
Example : `@Property NodePath myNode;`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with the current Godot 3.0 stable and `export` should work.

Have you tried the following code?

```
export var testNP = NodePath("AnimatedSprite/StaticBody2D")
```

If you don't see it immediately just run the script and the Nodepath variable should appear in the editor. You can then edit the Nodepath using the tree hierarchy.

Obviously, your path to the Node is different but it worked for me. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't use the var keyword. I'll try when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: It give me `undifined identifier var` and `found export intead of identifier`.

Comment: Could you paste a little code snippet? Do you use GDScript or C#?

Comment: Godot-d (dlang bindings) not C# or gdscript

Comment: Oh sorry, I was ignoring the d from Godot-D the whole time. Can't help you with dlang. But from your error message I would assume that you might need to specify the type of the variable like in `export string var_name = ... ` but I don't know if the export keyword is defined in dlang at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart The Scene To make Export Work.
i dont know but export keyword does not work on first time.